# Temporary failure resolving

Tags: networking, dns

I have issue with resolving name servers on my Rasberry Pi runing ARM Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS. Every time I ping for example Google.com i got:

`ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

This device is reaciving DNS from my router, and it is only affected device.

```
user@user:~$ nmcli dev show wlan0 | grep IP4
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.2/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.2
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out:
My `/etc/resolve.conf` was linked to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

```
ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jul 31  2020 resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

which was screwed because `/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` did not existed.
to resolve this I had to run:
`sudo mkdir /run/systemd/resolve` and later create `stub-resolv.conf` and add nameserver to it.